# Would this question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I haven't studied anything related to linguistics since high-school, so I'm not sure if this question makes any sense and is on-topic.

I would like to know if there are open problems related to grammars. What are the main lines of research? I was thinking whether every grammar can analyse correctly any sentence, axiomatic grammars, incompleteness, consistency and things like that.

The question is probably too broad, but I haven't seen any similar question and I think that it would be useful to have some broad questions in the beta phase.

But if the answer to the question is just no, it won't have much value.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't like questions that don't have single answers. Sometimes you can ask a different version of the same question though looking for a resource on the topic, such as a website or research paper. This seems plausible for your topic of interest here.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply.

Usually answers are not that short as we encourage to add reasons and explanations, so a simple "No" answer would be unlikely.

I'm not sure I got the core of your question but as long as it's not too broad, then it's fine. Being broad is never useful because your question would have little focus and be too hard to answer.

If you could narrow it in a reasonable way, not only its quality would be good, but it'd be easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what at present is done as to grammar research. I think a lot of activity is going into computer linguistics. But a desideratum as to grammar
would be an online grammar portal that could be considered as a standard grammar with a register that allows to find things immediately.
Another desideratum would be to develop a useful grammar terminology with a limited number of grammar terms that are easy to understand.
The grammar terminology is developing in a way that is out of proportion.